# Is there any text editor online capable of recording macros?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, javascript, text-editor

I am a looking for a good text editor with a simple and powerful macro-recording functionality that should:

- be open source, and
- JavaScript/jQuery based.

Optionals:

- Open multiple files would be great.
- Syntax highlighting isn't needed but would be great too.

Already know about [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/) but it doesn't satisfy the macros thing.

Comment: Do you require log-in/remembering what you were doing or anonymous?

Comment: Also how important is the JS based requirement? (Also curious as to *why* you want it to be JS/jQuery based?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact the textarea in which I am composing this answer supports macros. It can for you too with a little help from [wasavi](http://appsweets.net/wasavi/).

The wasavi editor is a vi work-alike that brings a large portion of vi functionality to the web. This includes macros using the usual <kbd>q</kbd> binding to start recording, followed by a single character to register the macro under. The next <kbd>q</kbd> from command mode terminates the macro recording. To replay it, hit <kbd>@</kbd> followed by the character you used to identify the recording.

You may use this functionality for any text-area on the web using the browser extensions ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dgogifpkoilgiofhhhodbodcfgomelhe), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wasavi/), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/wasavi/)) or [as a stand alone web-app](http://wasavi.appsweets.net/). For the source code see the project's [Github page](https://github.com/akahuku/wasavi).